# Castle Nvelocity - Getting started

Tags: c#, nvelocity

Im trying to follow this guide:

http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/usingit.html

Can you tell me what dlls I have to include to get his working:

```
VelocityEngine velocity = new VelocityEngine();

ExtendedProperties props = new ExtendedProperties();
velocity.Init(props);
```

I included the whole castle project and that still didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference NVelocity.dll. This doesn't seem to be part of the main Castle project.

The last stable release of this was 1.0.3 RC3 (according to [this](http://www.castleproject.org/castle/projects.html) page). You can get this whole release from [here](http://www.castleproject.org/castle/download.html), under the "1.0 Release Candidate 3" section. If you download the binaries, the NVelocity.dll is packaged inside a zip file called external-dependencies.zip.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help people starting with NVelocity:
http://chrisseroka.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/generating-html-document-from-template-using-nvelocity/